# How does #redirect_to get the domain to append a relative path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When using the Rails [redirect_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to) with a relative path, how does it determine the domain to combine with the relative path? Is there a method or env that is being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the Rails redirect_to with a relative path, it determines the domain to combine with the relative path by using the request.host method.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-redirect-to

Comment: Ah okay, so I guess my follow up question would be where the request.host method is pulling the domain from? Based on 

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c00c07b66e5645b4941cbda2c4457300a7a10755/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/url.rb#L214

It seems that request.host uses the method above, to generate the request.host return value from Host Header?

based on: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c00c07b66e5645b4941cbda2c4457300a7a10755/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/url.rb#L242